# Is there a limit of steam cards per day

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

So I have a question  about how steam cards work, specifically if there is a limit outside of the random factor to the card drops. So I know you can only get half of the cards total by just playing the game, but I am experiencing an issue where I have been idling in 13 games for the past 6.5 hours and haven't received a single card for any of them, even though I just installed them all for the first time (Meaning I have all my drops available). So is there a limit to the amount per day, because that would explain why I am not earning any. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I think they might have added a way to know when you've got multiple games launched, I no longer seem to get cards from farming like this, but I immediately started getting cards when idling in only one. Just an annecdote though

Comment: I'll give this a try

Answer (score 3):

Personally I found running many games at once does not work for me, I have gotten cards when it was 3 or less games at once.

Cards generally drop once every 30 minutes for most people when playing a single game I am unsure if this average stays the same when using multiple games.

I do not believe there is a limit to how many you can obtain in a day since there is a limit already associated to the total amount you can have.

**Things to keep in mind**

Level 10 you start getting foil cards.

Every 10 levels you increase your chances for booster pack by 20% at 100% it has (doubled)

Sources

[30 Minute 1](http://raidwarning.com/steam-trading-cards-101/)

[30 Minute 2](http://www.gamerswithjobs.com/node/115067?page=2)

[No Daily Limit Discussion 1](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/tradingcards/discussions/1/828939797141591124/)

[No Daily Limit Discussion 2](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/tradingcards/discussions/1/864971765359843429/)

http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq/

Comment: I agree with this for the first statement, the second I switched to only having 1 game running everything started to work and I started getting my cards.